# Using RestKit, is there a way I can run code when the object mapping on a single object completes?

Tags: ios, restkit, restkit-0.20

I'm implementing my property setter methods on my local object type so I can do some extra work when RestKit is setting my object values from a JSON payload; but I also need to do some work after I know for sure that, lets say, 3 of those properties have been set.

i.e instead of in each setter doing something like checking to see what properties have been set...

```
-(void) setSomeValue:(NSNumber *someValue){
   self.someValue  = someValue;
   //do some extra stuff here
   if(self.otherValue){
      //do some calculation using someValue and otherValue
   }
}

-(void) setOtherValue:(NSNumber *otherValue){
   self.otherValue  = otherValue;
   //do some extra stuff here
   if(self.someValue){
      //do some calculation using someValue and otherValue
   }
}
```

Is there some method I can implement where I would for sure know both or all of the properties have been mapped for one instance of a collection of objects?

Or is there at least a way that I can specify an order to which objects are mapped so I can ensure which ones are set before others that are dependant?

Comment: I guess this isn't in Core Data?

Comment: today, no not using core data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of implementing setters you can iterate through all objects after mapping operation completed:

```
[RKObjectManager sharedManager] getObjectsAtPath:@"path/to/my/objects" parameters:nil success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
    NSArray *objects = mappingResult.array;
    for (id obj in objects) {

       if ([obj isKindOfClass:[Entity class]]) {
          Entity *entity = obj;

          if (entity.someProperty && entity.anotherProperty) {
            //do stuff
          }
       }
    }
} failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

}];
```

Comment: Note that all of the objects may not be of the same class when you iterate the result in this way.